# Hamilton operator action in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, particle-physics, operators

I have a question about the action of the Hamilton operator in quantum field theory. At the moment I am trying to get into QFT and came across the following commutator relation:
\begin{align}
[H,\psi] &= \omega_k\psi & \omega_k=E=\sqrt{|\vec{k}|^2+ m}
\end{align}
where $H = \int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3 2\omega_k} \omega_k \sum_{\alpha} ({b_\alpha^+}b_\alpha+d_\alpha {d_\alpha^+})$ is the Hamilton operator and $\psi$ the Dirac field operator.

**Now my question is: What does this result tell me?**

**Edit:**
I don't really know how to be more specific but let me try. I don't know the physical interpretation of the result or in other words what physics can I learn from it? Does it simply mean, that H gives the energy of the particle? And does it also mean, that the Energy of the particle can't be measured at the same time as the particle state? I hope this gives you a better idea what I mean.

Comment: You have studied the quantum harmonic oscillator right?

Comment: @jacob1729 Yes.

Comment: The field is a collection of an infinity of particles and antiparticles, and the relation specifies how to find their energy, and, ultimately, their time evolution. You've studied this, no?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes.

Comment: OK, then, this is the Heisenberg equation of motion for the field operator *ψ*, and equivalently, for the individual oscillators *b*, *d*, and their conjugates. As usual, these equations are easy to solve, netting the explicit time dependence. What more would you ask from it?